# Radius of convergence is always $1$ proof.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Show that if $p(n)$ is any nontrivial polynomial, then the radius of convergence of the power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p(n)x^n$$ is always $1$.

So we use the ratio test to get $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = |x| \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{p(n+1)}{p(n)}\right|$.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any non-trivial polynomial $p$ the limit of $|\frac {p(x+1)} {p(x)}|$ as $ x \to\ \infty$ is $1$.

Let $p(x)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} a_kx^{k}$. Then $\frac {p(x+1)} {p(x)}=\frac {\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k(x+1)^{k}} {\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_kx^{k}}$. To see what happens when you let $x \to \infty$ simply divide the numerator and denominator by $x^{n}$ and then take the limit. You will see that the limit is $\frac {a_n} {a_n}=1$

Comment: How did you get $\frac{a_n}{a_n}=1$?

Comment: @squenshl When you divide all the terms by $x^{n}$ an take the limit term by term you see that all the terms except one has limit zero and you will be left with just $a_n$ in the numerator and also $a_n$ in the denominator. For example the second last term in the numerator would be $a_{n-1}/x$ when you divide by $x^{n}$ and the limit of this as $x \to \infty$ is $0$.